# XCode: AppIcon sizes?

Tags: icons, xcode7

There are so many different sizes. I spent a lot of time in creating these sizes from one master file. How do you handle this task? Is there a tool? I found an internet site, which wants to get your files! 
Even after I inserted all of the sizes Xcode reminds me for an 76x76 icon. But there is no placeholder and no size combined by a factor results in that dimensions. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no tool for the creating automatic app icons form the master file but you can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) for the solution.